# Compare filenames (without extension) from "Dir1" to subfolder "Dir2" assuming I'm at "Dir1"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to compare Dir1 and Dir2 file names without extension. Dir2 is a subfolder of Dir1 so I'm launching the script from Dir1.

```
Dir1/proof1.txt
Dir1/proof2.txt
Dir1/proof3.txt
Dir1/proof4.txt
Dir1/proof5.txt
Dir1/proof6.txt

Dir1/Dir2/proof1.png
Dir1/Dir2/proof2.png
Dir1/Dir2/proof5.png
```

And the output I wanted is the file names that exists at Dir1 but not at Dir2:

```
proof3
proof4
proof6
```

This is what I'm using (not working) to find Files that are at Dir1 but not at Dir2:

(find . -printf '%P\n' | grep -v Dir2 && find Dir2/ -printf '%P\n' && find Dir2/ -printf '%P\n') | sort | uniq -u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do...

```
$ comm -23 <(ls -1 | cut -d. -f1) <(ls -1 Dir2/ | xargs -n 1 basename | cut -d. -f1)
```

may not work as intended if your filenames have `.` in them other than separating extension.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked well! Do you know why the output shows "proof1" on top if "proof1" It's at Dir1 and Dir2? Here's the output:
**proof1**  proof3  proof4  proof 6

Comment: since extensions are trimmed perhaps you have two copies?  adding `uniq` after `cut` in both should fix it.

Comment: Nope, there aren't two copies but your "uniq" solution works! Now I'm trying to accept whitespaces and "." other than separating extension, but I think this is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Only testet with clean filenames without whitespace:

```
for f in proof*.txt ; do test -f "Dir2/$(basename "$f" .txt).png" || echo no match "$f"; done
```

- Test -f tests, if a file exists and is an ordinary file.
- basename removes the extension, if given